# angular ssr with @fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I use Angular SSR and I want to get signature browser or macAddress to specify user browser, When I use @fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs package and build my project ssr and server ssr the page not loaded in web {head and body empty tag}

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in your JS console / server ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it works just fine with the [FingerprintJS npm package](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs/blob/master/docs/api.md#webpackrollupnpmyarn).

Also, for some configurations, you might encounter an error with the unavailable `document.location` API. Therefore, I'd recommend rendering it explicitly on the client-side using Angular's [isPlatformBrowser](https://angular.io/api/common/isPlatformBrowser) function.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import FingerprintJS from '@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'fpjs-angular';

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
      const fpPromise = FingerprintJS.load()
        ; (async () => {
          // Get the visitor identifier when you need it.
          const fp = await fpPromise
          const result = await fp.get()
          console.log(result.visitorId)
        })()
    }
  }
}
```